# Is there any way to get dynamic data from firebase in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout

I am updating data in firebase as String. This includes texts, links, video links. As shown in image- [Screenshot of content data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E90vVR0tfMvUg-TENXRg-Hl4Nkilt16t/view?usp=sharing)
Now I want to retrieve Content in flutter application. I am retrieving Content like below-

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection("Insights")
            .orderBy("Time", descending: true)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                      child: Text(
                    (snapshot.data.docs[index]['Content'])
                        .toString()
                        .replaceAll("\\n", "\n"),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
                  )),
                );
              });
        });
  }
}
```

When I am retrieving data like above , its showing me text and links as String. But I want to get data like [Inkwell in between text and links to video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b9ec6315HgPxB2-QjIQmDVWbgqeDgvs8/view?usp=sharing). As shown in image, it have inkwell ,texts and image shown.

But in my case , it's everything showing as text.

Is there any way to include these data dynamically without being explicitly defined in flutter or any way to handle them in firebase?

Comment: you could simply add a separate parameter for URL to make things simple, Like this
    {"content":content,
"url":'www.youtube.com/?1243'}

Comment: @Ayyaz.meo Thanks for quick reply. If i do so, how will I handle the url tagging to text. It means I need to explicitly mention the Inkwell in flutter. What if I need to get data like I attached image with multiple inkwell. How will I handle it then?

Comment: like this:
InkWell(onTap:(){
launchUrl(snapshot.data.docs[index]['url'])},child:ListViewBuilder(snapshot.data.docs[index]['Content']))

Comment: @Ayyaz.meo Thank you for detailed explaination but again my doubt is how will I map url to text i.e. which url will attach to which text in case of multiple inkwell object. Like I have attached in output image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can click the link to view the youtube video using the following snippet.
On top of the link, it will redirect you to the provided link.

```
InkWell(
            onTap: (){
              launch(Uri.parse(snapshot.data.docs[index]['Content']));
            },
              child: Text(
                (snapshot.data.docs[index]['Content'])
                    .toString()
                    .replaceAll("\\n", "\n"),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              )),
```

Instead of using a container replace it with InkWell.

Note: for launching the URL I have used the package `url_launcher`:https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I forget to mention that , content includes text as well other than links and I have updated question as well . I have attached output as well. Will it work with rest of the text as well?